# Don't understand battery test results

Tags: battery

My battery tested  at 660A. Its CCA rating is 760A.  Its 100 deg temp here. Shouldn't a good battery read much higher than 760 CCA at this temperature? Or is the test equipment compensated for ambient temperature?  Thanks

Comment: Can you describe how it was tested?

Comment: Is it a "good" battery or is it a battery that is 3 years old and still useful but not as capable as a brand new one?

Answer (score 1):

100F will not severely impact a CCA test.  I assume you had the test done with a tester, like at a car parts place. Most of the testers are compensated for temperature, which is normally a bigger issue with colder temperatures.

Battery ratings (and those for other things) are for new components, in perfect condition.  After you use your battery, or it sits unused, it will degrade in performance.  Sometimes more than less.  Is your car not starting well with this battery?

A drop from 760CCA to 660CCA would not be anything that I would normally be concerned about.